# Blocking USA traffic without blocking search engine bots?

Tags: .htaccess, seo, search-engine

Dear Friends Need a big advice from you.
I have a website that i don't want any traffic from USA(website contains only local contents). Since most of the visitors comes to my website from search engines,I don't want to block those search engine bots.

I know how to

- block ip addresses from .htaccess.
- redirecting users from Geo location.

  I think if I block USA ips then my website won't be indexed in Google or yahoo.So even I don't want any USA traffic I need my webpages to be indexed in Google and yahoo.

Depend on the `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` I can allow bots to crawl my webpages.
One of my friend told that if I block USA visitors except bots,Google will **blacklist** my website for disallowing Google indexed pages for USA visitors.

Is this true? If so what should I do for this problem? Any advices are greatly appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. using JS redirect for US users. This will allow most of the search engine bots to visit your website.
2. using Robots.txt to tell Google where and what to read
   http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156449
3. there is a way to add Googlebot's IP addresses (or just the name: http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=80553) as an exception.
4. use the geotargeting and block the pages with a JS div or just add a banner that tell your users that they can't use the website from their location

hope this helps, 
cheers,

Answer (score 0):

I'm only answering this here because someone was smart enough to spam Google's "Webmaster Central Help Forum" with a link drop.  I know this answer is more of a comment, but I blame the question, had it been asked in webmasters SE, this answer would be more on-topic.

---

**1** Why block US visitors?  I understand there can be some legal reasons (eg gambling). But you could just disable those features for US visitors and allow them to see the content and a banner that explains that the site is not available for US visitors.  Search engines won't have any issue with that (they're incapable of gambling or purchasing stuff anyway) and there's no cloaking either.

**2** Victor's answer contains a few issues IMO:

> 1. Using JS redirect for US users. This will allow most of the search engine bots to visit your website.

This was probably correct at the time of writing, but these days Google (and >probably some other search engines as well) are capable of running the JavaScript and will therefore also follow the redirect.

> 2. Using Robots.txt to tell Google where and what to read.

I'd suggest using the robots meta tag or X-Robots-Tag header instead, or respond with a 451 status code to all US visitors.

> 3. There is a way to add Googlebot's IP addresses as an exception.

Cloaking.

> 4. Use the geotargeting and block the pages with a JS div or just add a banner that tell your users that they can't use the website from their location.

Totally agree, do this.